# Go to Next activity while the Button is clicked & Return when Released

Tags: android, android-activity, ontouch

I have a OnTouch Button,Which while the button is click goes to the next activity using motion event,but I want it to stay in the Next activity only for the time the button is clicked and then return...If it seems to be perplexing ,here is the code-:

```
   @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            while (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActionActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){


            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: put post handle for 5 seconds in second activity and after finish second activity.

Comment: I could be wrong, but you are starting a new activity, which replaces the current. So the touch should be "reset". You could try to put an Action_up event in the second activity and start the intent to the former (or just fake a backpressed)

Comment: I don´t think that this is not very easy to implement. The question is, what´s your goal? Maybe there are other approaches for your goal.

Comment: no,current one would not reset,you just start second activity but dont finish first activity.

Comment: Would probably be a lot easier using a fragment to show on press.

Comment: My Goal is to stay in the next activity for the time I have clicked the button and then return to the main activity on button releasing,btw the button too does not exist in the Next activity @Opiatefuchs

Comment: @user6547359 could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user6547359 On your first comment- The button is not existing on leaving the previous activity & how do I fake a backpress?

Comment: @Vasant how can I go back but?

Comment: @Anonymous I was just suggesting something to try (when 2nd activity opens you are still touching, so Action_Up might fire when you lift the finger, so you could in second activity put a onBackPressed() to fake the back pressed).

Comment: On the Fragment part (I don't know what you actually want to show but it shouldn't matter) In the activity on action_down show the fragment, on action_up hide it.

Comment: @user6547359 Thanks for your suggestion,but I don't think the fake BackPress works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same onTouch on root view of the next activity and finish the activty ACTION_UP

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
           finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

});
```

**(Update) Tested Answer:**

First Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

    viewGroup.setOnTouchListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        return true;
    } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        SecondActivity.activity.get().finish();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Second Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static WeakReference<Activity> activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    activity = new WeakReference<Activity>(this);
}
```

}

1. Don't use 'while' in onTouch
2. finish second activity from first activity using static Activity Object,

**This is working**

Comment: I will let you know in a second

Comment: It's yet the same,When I click the button it goes to the next activity but I do not go back on releasing the button(plus the button does not even exist in the NextActivity

Comment: I updated the answer. I tested by myself now and its working like you need.

Comment: From old memories, static activities = bad for lifecycle issues (I might be remembering wrong though).

Comment: To avoid that you can use activity WeakReference. In this way you can avoid MemoryLeaks. ANSWER UPDATED

Comment: Thanks,But the 
SecondActivity.activity.finish();
&
activity = this;
lines of codes are causing an error+the implementing of ViewGroup is causing an error too

Comment: Then its some other error on your side. This thing is working as i am checking by myself. Also the answer is update. Have a look

Comment: I went through my code again,could not find any issue from my side,a last favor could you send me a gif/image of how is it working on your end?

Comment: Ohh found a mistake on my side ,forgot to define this
public static WeakReference<Activity> activity;
My bad!,but yet the implementation of ViewGroup is an error idk why?

Comment: It works just fine without the implementation and got rid of viewGroup.setOnTouchListener(this);   and it worked!!!!!.....Thanks a ton!!,